# Cant able to connect to AWS S3 from springboot application

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-java

we are working on Spring boot applicaation to connect with AWS S3.

```
  final AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);


        AmazonS3 s3client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                .withRegion(Regions.US_WEST_2)
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials))
                .build();
```

while creating the AwsCredentials object line itself we facing the below issue

```
java.lang.SecurityException: class "com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package
```

we didn't understand what is the issue?

so anyone know what is the issue and how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

There are AWS Tutorials that discuss how to interact with Amazon S3 from a Spring boot application.

You code is V1 and all AWS current tutorials are V2. I recommend using the Java SDK for AWS Version 2.

Here is an AWS Tutorial that shows you how to create a Spring Boot application that does interact with Amazon S3. In addition to S3, this example app also uses these AWS services:

- Amazon Rekognition
- Amazon SES
- AWS Elastic Beanstalk

To learn how to use the AWS SDK for Java V2 to develop a Spring Boot application that invokes Amazon S3 and other services, see this URL:  https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/usecases/creating_photo_analyzer_app